# How to tell Mathematica that a limit converges to a product of two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have looked through the manual and Im simply just stuck trying to make *Mathematica* solve this:

[image]

```
Limit[
  -m ((Abs[r + 1/2 λ k] - Abs[r - 1/2 λ k])/(Abs[r + 1/2 λ k] Abs[r - 1/2 λ k])),
  λ -> 0]
```

I have renamed ℓ to  λ, however I simply cannot figure out how to tell that the limit produces `m l = μ`.

Could someone please show me how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `m` by `μ/λ` to impose the condition `m λ = μ`.
I assume `r = {x, y, z}` and `k = {0, 0, 1}`; then you want [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) for vectors, since [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is for complex/real numbers.

```
Block[{r = {x, y, z}, k = {0, 0, 1}},
 Limit[-m ((Norm[r + 1/2 λ k] - Norm[r - 1/2 λ k]) /
         (Norm[r + 1/2 λ k] Norm[r - 1/2 λ k])) /. m -> μ/λ,
       λ -> 0] // Simplify[#, r ∈ Reals] &
 ]
(*  -((z μ)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2))  *)
```

If you want to put it in terms of `r`, it's easiest just to retype it.  Or if you must show *Mathematica* who's the boss, try

```
Simplify[-((z μ)/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)),
 Norm[r]^2 == x^2 + y^2 + z^2 && Norm[r] >= 0]
(*  -((z μ)/Norm[r]^3)  *)
```

Note that `Norm[r] >= 0` seems extraneous.

Answer (score 2):

```
r = {x, y}; 
a = {a1, a2};
expr = 1/Sqrt[(r - a).(r - a)] - 1/Sqrt[(r + a).(r + a)];
(Series[expr, {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. x^2 -> R^2 - y^2 //
   PowerExpand // Factor

(*  (2 (a1 x + a2 y))/R^3   *)
```

Have fun!